# Match IDs taken from 2 inputs (JSON) and do something if positive

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, if-statement

Here's a sample of a JSON entry output from Feedbin's [entries.json](https://github.com/feedbin/feedbin-api/blob/master/content/entries.md):

```
[
  {
    "id": 2077,
    "title": "Objective-C Runtime Releases",
    "url": "http:\/\/mjtsai.com\/blog\/2013\/02\/02\/objective-c-runtime-releases\/",
    "author": "Michael Tsai",
    "content": "<p><a href=\"https:\/\/twitter.com\/bavarious\/status\/297851496945577984\">Bavarious<\/a> created a <a href=\"https:\/\/github.com\/bavarious\/objc4\/commits\/master\">GitHub repository<\/a> that shows the differences between versions of <a href=\"http:\/\/www.opensource.apple.com\/source\/objc4\/\">Apple\u2019s Objective-C runtime<\/a> that shipped with different versions of Mac OS X.<\/p>",
    "summary": "Bavarious created a GitHub repository that shows the differences between versions of Apple\u2019s Objective-C runtime that shipped with different versions of Mac OS X.",
    "published": "2013-02-03T01:00:19.000000Z",
    "created_at": "2013-02-04T01:00:19.127893Z"
  }
]
```

Here's my function which authenticates with Feedbin's API, retrieves the JSON document, and prints title and URL for the first 5 results.

```
<?php
// JSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = 'https://api.feedbin.me/v2/entries.json';

$username = 'username';  // authentication
$password = 'password';  // authentication

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password   // authentication
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting JSON result string

$cache_feedbin = '/BLAHBLAH/'.sha1($json_url).'.json';

    if(file_exists($cache_feedbin) && filemtime($cache_feedbin) > time() - 1000){
        // if a cache file newer than 1000 seconds exist, use it
        $data_feedbin = file_get_contents($cache_feedbin);
    } else {
        $data_feedbin = $result;
        file_put_contents($cache_feedbin, $data_feedbin);
    }

    foreach (array_slice(json_decode($data_feedbin), 0, 5) as $obj) {
        $feedbin_title = $obj->title;
        $feedbin_url = $obj->url;
        echo '<li><a href="', $feedbin_url, '">', $feedbin_title, '</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

It works like a charm. What I'd love to try is mixing this with [unread_entries.json](https://github.com/feedbin/feedbin-api/blob/master/content/unread-entries.md), which retuns an array of entry_ids of unread items. Something like:

```
[4087,4088,4089,4090,4091,4092,4093,4094,4095,4096,4097]
```

My goal is: check within the foreach which IDs match with the IDs of unread items taken from unread_entries.json. For the IDs that match (so, unread items) do nothing, for ALL THE OTHERS, display an image which says "READ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BONUS ROUND:

Updated example to include a function for caching JSON requests:

```
define('CACHE_PATH',  '/tmp');    // Might want to change this
define('CACHE_SECS',  1000);
define('API_USERNAME',  'username');
define('API_PASSWORD',  'password');

$entries = fetchJSON('https://api.feedbin.me/v2/entries.json', API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD, CACHE_SECS);
$unread_msgs = fetchJSON('https://api.feedbin.me/v2/unread_entries.json', API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD, CACHE_SECS);
foreach ($entries as $obj) {
    $is_read = !in_array($obj->id, $unread_msgs);   // Read if not present in unread
    $feedbin_title = $obj->title;
    $feedbin_url = $obj->url;

    $output = '<li><a href="'.$feedbin_url.'">'. $feedbin_title;
    if ($is_read) {
        $output .= ' <img src="icon-read.png" title="READ" />';
    }
    $output .= '</a></li>';
    echo $output;
}

/** Return a JSON decoded object/array */
function fetchJSON($json_url, $username = null, $password = null, $cache_secs = null)   {
    $cache_file = CACHE_PATH.'/'.sha1($json_url).'.json';
    $data = null;

    // Check if we need to request new content
    if (!$cache_secs || !file_exists($cache_file) || filemtime($cache_file) < time() - $cache_secs) {
        // Initializing curl
        $ch = curl_init( $json_url );

        // Configuring curl options
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        );

        // If username given add to curl opts
        if (!empty($username))  {
            $options[CURLOPT_USERPWD] = $username . ":" . $password;
        }

        // Setting curl options
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

        // Getting results
        $data = curl_exec($ch); // Getting JSON result string
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($cache_secs) {
            file_put_contents($cache_file, $data);
        }
    } else  {
        // Got data from the cache
        $data = file_get_contents($cache_file);
    }

    return !empty($data) ? json_decode($data) : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) I'm trying but I'm getting a "syntax error, unexpected ',' after $feedbin_title". BTW I think that I need another auth for $unread_msgs.. username/password are the same I already sent for $result.. should I send 'em again?

Comment: Sorry, there was a trailing comma after feedbin_title. Fixed the above cove.

Comment: A line in php has to end with a semicolon, so what do you think is causing that error?

Comment: I'm testing this and will let you know in a second :)

Comment: Uhm.. here's the function live:
http://ffio.it/feedbin.php Of the 5 entries I read only the first (Paste and Go Hotkey, Incolla e cerca su Firefox come su Opera). So I should see the image only on it. Problem is it's present for all... I updated the cache.

Comment: Can you add `print_r($unread_msgs)` directly above the `foreach()` and also change the line to `$output = '<li>['.$obj->id.'] <a href="'. $feedbin_url.'">'. $feedbin_title;`  so that we can see what ID the message has

Comment: I think the problem is it's not fetching $unread_msgs because I need to re-authenticate with feedbin username/password (as for entries.json). In fact print_r($unread_msgs); printed nothing..

Comment: Yes.. This is in the error logs:
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.feedbin.me/v2/unread_entries.json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Ahh - you will need to either fetch with CURL (like you are doing with  unread_entries.json), or alternatively, you can see my edited answer to see how to do it with `file_get_contents()` by passing it a context.

Comment: While you was editing the question I also tried to make the auth thing.. here's what I came up with :)
`$unread_msgs_url = 'https://api.feedbin.me/v2/unread_entries.json';
// Initializing curl
$ch2 = curl_init( $unread_msgs_url );

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch2, $options );

$unread_msgs = curl_exec($ch2); // Getting JSON result string`

.. so I don't need to repeat username/password. It works (at least now `print_r($unread_msgs);` works. But still the READ image is present for all entries.

Comment: [32097762,32149805] are unread. So the read icon should be only on first and last 2

Comment: if you are calling `print_r` before then the output doesn't look correct. EG. It doesn't look like `json_decode()` has been called to turn it into an array

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle your caching better for you too

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = [4087,4088,4089,4090,4091,4092,4093,4094,4095,4096,4097];

$id = 4087;

if (isset($ids[$id]) )
{
    echo "do something\n";
}
else
{
    echo "do something else\n";
}
```